# Okay to push directly to gh-pages branch without pushing to master branch?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am hosting a blog on github as a project page and I find it tiresome to push to master first and then to gh-pages.I found that pushing to gh-pages directly works too.I wanted to know if it is okay to push to gh-pages directly without pushing to master first.

Comment: If the repository is nothing else than a site, then you don't even need a master branch.

Comment: Yeah It is just a site.Can I safely delete it then?Please add an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`master` is just a name for a branch, same as `gh-pages`.

Conventionally it is better to keep your main development branch called `master`, however you can safely delete `master` and use `gh-pages` only.

Answer (score 0):

Correct - you don't even need a master branch.

Here's a guide on how to [delete the master branch from GitHub](http://oli.jp/2011/github-pages-workflow/#deleting-master):

> 1. Make the `gh-pages` branch your default branch on GitHub: Repository Administration > Options > Set “Default Branch” setting to something other than `master`
> 2. Delete the master branch on GitHub using `git push origin :master`
> 3. Delete the master branch in your local repo (once you’ve checked everything is working!) using `git branch -d master`